# combination of lenses for undefined focal length

Tags: optics, laser, lenses

Good morning!
I am not an optics specialist, but I need to know if it's possible to do what I tried to visualise in my picture.
[image: something like this.]

Basicly I want to merge two beams into one. I am thinking of using a lens with an undefined focal length.
What "mystery lens" would I have to use?
Is that even possible?
Thanks in advance.

- Linus

Comment: What do you mean by "an undefined focal length"?  Do you want the spots to be defocused? Focused at infinity?  Please clarify.

Comment: Sure. I don't really know how I should express myself, but I mean that the energy that is on 15 cm should be the same amount as the energy on 35 cm.

Comment: If it is just these two specific points, you can use any imaging system to project one image plane onto another; these are called [conjugate focal planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_focal_plane).

Comment: I mean the complete beam should have the same energy as the focal point from my first lens (the 10 cm mark in this case).

Comment: The energy in the beam doesn't change as it travels, minus some inevitable scattering and absorption; but the beam will diverge - it gets more spread out.  Perhaps you want the intensity to be unchanging: the power per unit of area?

Comment: Often people want to do the opposite of what you are asking. They take a narrow laser beam and expand it. Google beam expander and look at images. You will see several ways to do it. You can of course run them backward. Shine a laser in the wide end, and it will come out narrower. Shine two lasers in the wide end, and they will come out closer together.

Comment: But as these optics are quite expensive, do you guys know any cheap online shops?

Comment: @mmesser314 Also, one more question. Is the angle the laser goes into the lens important?

Comment: The angles, distances between lenses, and focal lengths of lenses are generally important. http://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/lasers/beam-expanders/ will help you get started. If you are doing this as a hobby and want to make a cheap beam expander, just buy cheap lenses and figure out how to mount them yourself. You can find cheap lenses if you google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lens can be used to make two beams parallel and closer together. But I suspect that isn't what you are trying to do.

Often people want to do the opposite of what you are asking. They take a narrow laser beam and expand it. Google beam expander and look at images. You will see several ways to do it. You can run them backward. Shine a laser in the wide end, and it will come out narrower. Shine two lasers in the wide end, and they will come out closer together.

Sometimes people want to reduce a beams diameter. For example, in a laser drilling application. A narrow beam drills a small hole. A narrow beam is more intense because the power of the beam is concentrated on a smaller spot.

There are drawbacks to a narrow beam. A beam is never perfectly collimated because of diffraction. It always spreads a little. A narrow beam spreads more.

The angles, distances between lenses, and focal lengths of lenses are generally important. Though the distance from the lasers to the first lens probably won't make much difference. edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/lasers/… will help you get started. If you are doing this as a hobby and want to make a cheap beam expander, just buy cheap lenses and figure out how to mount them yourself. You can find cheap lenses if you google.

What you probably want is a beam combiner. Google that for more information. You can buy them, but they are not going to be cheap.

Comment: Do you mean these little glass cubes?
I found some in an old dvd drive...
Do you think I could use them?